# Is there a repository for downloading sample component logs of openstack?

Tags: redhat, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-swift, openstack-neutron

I am new to OpenStack, is there a repository where I can download OpenStack sample logs of each component to be used for analysis. I need to look for logs of each component that has a log level af error and critical.  Found some logs on github and openstack.org but it is more on nova, glance and neutron logs for the other components there is no log file that can be found, need to find logs about cinder, swift, heat and ceilometer can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get logs from Openstack Zuul. It's the CI infrastructure for Openstack that tests all new code. It's not going to be exactly the same as regular production logs, as it may contain experimental code, but should give you an idea at least.
http://zuul.openstack.org/

If you click on one of the jobs to expand the list, and then pick one of the jobs you should be able to get logs from all components used in that test.